# Why doesn't __declspec(novtable) work on a template specialization?

Tags: visual-c++, vtable

I have a base class for a generic callable that I'm marking `__declspec(novtable)`:

```
template<class F> struct callable;
template<class R, class... T>
struct __declspec(novtable) callable<R(T...)>
{ virtual R operator()(T...) volatile { return R(); } };
```

but somehow this does *not* error like [it's supposed to](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/novtable?view=msvc-160#example):

```
int main()
{
        auto temp = new callable<void()>();
        temp->operator()();
}
```

Why is `novtable` not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently Visual C++ looks at `__declspec(novtable)` **on the template, not its specializations**!
This doesn't make sense to me (is it a bug?), but the "solution" is to write this:

```
template<class F> struct __declspec(novtable) callable;
```